# Why I am getting gradle error in flutter android project?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, dart

I have no idea what this error means, I have never seen it before. This app uses firebase sign in and google sign in for login.
This is the error, exception I am getting after `flutter run` command

```
* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type FileHasher using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher().
> Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
  Owner PID: 19528
  Our PID: 24344
  Owner Operation: 
  Our operation: 
  Lock file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have another instance of flutter process or android process that is using the gradle instance.
The easiest way to solve this is to restart you computer.
Or you can find the other process and kill it if you had such knowledge.